# data analysis of categorial dicothomical variables

Tags: r, logistic, model, binary-data

I have the following dataset

[image]

I would like to calculate the frequency distribution of the response F or G in each participant, for each condition (MIO,TUO, NEUTRO) for a total of 15 images representing 15 distances, do I have to perform a logistic model? Does someone know how to implement it in R, or in SPSS? and how I should frame the data?

Comment: I guess you need to go with ANOVA: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/340129/anova-with-binary-dependent-variable (probit link)

Comment: Can you give more context? What does your variables represent? You say *response F or G ...*, but we see only F in the table, and the column name is `Stimulus.F` , not response ...

Comment: Ok. F and G mean yes or not, here you can see just F, but if I scroll down there are some G as well. The column Stimulus means "Stimulus Response". Basically participants see 15 images about 15 distances for each priming (MIO, TUO, NEUTRO), and they have to decide subjectively whether the distance is "Near"  YES=G  OR NOT=F.

Comment: I have to calculate a probability threshold that signals the passage from F to G

Comment: RTs add information about the time to take the decision to respond, so they are informative of the uncertainty in giving the response.